# How to restore svn repository after installation of windows & SVN tool

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Due to my Pc's motherboard failure i had to re install hardware and operating system as well. previously it was windowx xp where my svn were installed and configured. My svn repository directory were `D:\svn-repos\code\conf.....`  (version TortoiseSVN-1.6.16.21511-win32-svn-1.6.17)

currently i have installed operating system windows 7

After re installing OS and SVN i am not getting any way out how to map/restore my old repository ***svn-repos*** to use. I can create new repository but this is not required. I have to reuse my old repository ***svn-repos***.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Repository is just a bunch of files.

Answer (score 0):

as @zerkms noted, SVN repository is just a bunch of files holding the versionning data!

just place your backed up files (from `D:\svn-repos\code\...`)
anywhere you like (maybe at the same spot)
and you can just point your WC to the new location or check-out a new Working-Copy.